# Physics stack exchange styling issue in Chrome when not logged in

Tags: bug, design

Looking at this question on physics.stackexchange:

[What are washers for?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134705/what-are-washers-for)

The highlighted heading (Questions) looks odd. I'm not logged in to that site and I'm using Chrome.

[image: Odd styling screenshot]

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6114/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic rather, exact duplicate of!

Comment: True this is a duplicate, but I think it is a bug, the original question is tagged 'discussion'. I don't think the accepted answer for the original question is sound. Perhaps I should try and get the other question re-tagged as a bug...

Comment: But is it a bug in the SE code or a bug in Chrome?

Comment: @JohnRennie well I think web developers are at the mercy of browser behaviour whether it's by design or not. My view would be regardless of it being a Chrome fault, I'd still want my website to handle it.

Comment: @ForkandBeard I've seen the same problem on other webpages as well. It occured to me only after an update of Chrome. This is a bug imo.